# Pandas totalling balances with date timeline from multiple sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I have three sheets inside one excel spreadsheet. I am trying to obtain the output listed below, or something close to it. The desired outcome is to know when there will be a shortage so that I can attempt to re-actively order and prevent the shortage. All of these, except for the output, is on one excel file. Each are different sheets. How hard will this be to achieve, is this possible? Note that in all sheets listed, there are tons of other data columns so positional references to columns may be needed, or using iloc to call upon columns by name.

```
instock sheet 
product         someother       datapoint   qty
5.25            1               2           100
5.25            1               3           200
6               2               1           50
6               4               1           500




ordered
product         something       ordernum        qty     date
5 1/4           abc             52521           50      07/01/2019
5 1/4           ddd             22911           100     07/28/2019
6               eeee            72944           10      07/5/2019


promised
product         order       qty         date
5 1/4           456         300         06/12/2019
5 1/4           789         50          06/20/2019
5 1/4           112         50          07/20/2019
6               113         800         07/22/2019
5 1/4           144         50          07/28/2019
9               155         100         08/22/2019




Output
product     date        onhand      qtyordered      commited        balance     shortage
5.25        06/10       300                                         300         n
5.25        06/12       300                         300             0           n
5.25        06/20       0                           50              -50         y
5.25        07/01       -50         50                              0           n
6           07/05       550         10              0               560         n
5.25        07/20       0                           50              -50         y
6           07/22       560         0               800             -240        y
5.25        07/28       -50         100             50              0           n
9           08/22       0           0               100             -100        y
```

Comment: This is an awfully broad question.There are multiple steps here. I suspect you could do it in less than 20 lines of code.

Comment: id be happy to try and provide more context, and can you point me in the direction as to things that might get me closer to the desired output with those ~20 lines of code?

Comment: I don't have a lot of time today, but here are a couple of things to look at: read the sheets into a dictionary of dataFrames with useful names. Perform uniformity of variables across each dataFrame. For example, convert the date variables to actual datetime or similar and convert 5 1/4 to 5.25. Finally, use the pandas `concat` function to combine the dataFrames into a single dataFrame. Maybe the hardest thing is the 5 1/4 to 5.25 conversion, but there is probably a post on SO about it. If not, you could use a dictionary to map 1/4 to 0.25, then split the 5 1/4 variable map and recombine.

Comment: if i understand what your saying - i dont think i can combine the three sheets into one because there are a lot of other columns. probably 20 in each sheet.

Comment: is the only way to get to this output by combining all sheets into one? @Imo

Comment: Well, you will probably want to drop the variables that you don't need for the final output. From the example of your desired output, it looks like you want a single dataFrame. You can always keep the others around, so it's not really a destructive process. Also, you may need to use `merge` or `join` rather than `concat` to achieve the end result or perhaps a combination of both.